# How to Scroll Me with smoothly scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I having problem with my scroll me function to not go smoothly but instead it start slowly and then it moves quickly

```js
 $("#scrollme").click(function () {

        var ele = $(this).closest("row").find(".row");

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {

            $('#scrollme').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollme").offset().top + 30
            }, 'slow');
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollme").offset().top + 30
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: The default easing of JQuery's `animate()` is 'swing', you could change it to 'linear' see: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use scrollTo Native method :

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Final code :

```
$("#scrollme").click(function () {

    var ele = $(this).closest("row").find(".row");

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {
        document.querySelector('#scrollme').scrollTo({
            top: $("#scrollme").offset().top + 30,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    } else {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: $("#scrollme").offset().top + 30,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a small note. Using scrollTo with the options object, this is not supported in Edge, Safari. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo